CA-Clipper 5.2 function equivalent to FileToStr() & StrToFile() function of Foxpro
I am trying to convert text file to PDF file using CA-Clipper 5.2. I have got a code for this purpose in Foxpro. There, two functions have been used - FileToStr() & StrToFile(). I could not understand which functions in Clipper will be equivalent to these Foxpro functions.
Is there any function in CA-Clipper 5.2 available which is equivalent to FileToStr() & StrToFile() function of Foxpro. Or any code for text file to PDF file conversion can be shared written in Clipper 5.2
